# ESP32 - High current in deep sleep

Tags: esp32

I'm developing an application on ESP32 using the deep-sleep feature to save battery. I read that ESP32 consumes only uA when it works on deep-sleep.

I bought a board from Az-Delivery called D1-R32 with ESP32-WROOM-32 inside.

[image: Text]

I programmed it to enter in deep sleep, and I used some AA batteries to power it. I also powered on my oscilloscope and I used a shunt resistor (1 ohm - 1%) to measure the current flowing from the batteries to the ESP32 board.

The first measure I obtained is about 12 mA. I tried to change the LDO regulator, because the one that the board has is the AMS1117, and that LDO regulator has a quiescent current of 10 mA, so I thought... problem solved?

I replaced the LDO regulator for another one that has 70 uA quiescent current. I powered the ESP32 modules with the batteries, connected the oscilloscope again and now I get 6 mA.

I also tried to disconnect the on state LED. It only dropped to 5.7 mA.

Is there something on this board, that I can modify to achieve a power consumption of uA?

Comment: What components are on the board?

Comment: How much current does it draw when in active mode?

Comment: What about the USB-to-Serial converter?

Comment: @HandyHowie About 30-40 mA

Comment: @StarCat, I quitted it from the board and it only reduced 1-2 mA

Comment: Check out this [answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/530151/79070) with some code for the gpios that reduced sleep from 77uA to 7uA. Also, there is an interesting [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajt7vtgKNNM) from Andreas Spiess testing several ESP32 boads for low power design with a table (link in description) summarizing the result.

Comment: Try to put all unused & floating GPIO pins to the OUTPUT mode